# Angular - binding data a form

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that `POST` all data that is entered, when saving.  But when I refresh the page, not all entries are bound to their respective input fields.

It is a bit strange because I am using `ng-model` on all the fields.

Here is an example of what doesn't bind:

```
<input name="full_name" ng-model="user.full_name" type="text" required></input>
```

and here is one that does bind:

```
<input name="address" ng-model="user.address" type="text" required></input>
```

Has anyone run into this issue, or notice something I may be missing?

Comment: You need to do the update through Angular ($resource).

Comment: @finishingmove are you referring to the controller?

Comment: need a lot more details. Is data available when page is refreshed?

Comment: @charlietfl  The data is available, it shows up in the POST, when I save, after refresh only a 10 out of 14 items are bound.  They all have ng-model="user.xxxx"

Comment: Angular expects the server to return a representation of the POSTed/PUTed object. It then updates the bindings to reflect the new data, meaning if you do POST /user {name: "marty"} it expects a response {id: 12345, name: "marty"}

Comment: you say `refresh` but if you mean complete page refresh, javascript doesn't maintain state when page reloads, thus i asked if data is available on refresh. Need more details to troubleshoot. Create a demo

Answer (score 0):

It could be the browser remembering your last input in the forms. So after refreshing, the browser pre-populates the form and angular doesn't update the scope. There is a [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/6NlucSskQjY) about that. The best solution I found is to add autocomplete="off" in the inputs of the forms. Because after refreshing, there is no way angular could be remembering your last input in the form, unless you are using cookies for that wich you are obviously not.